# How to set a TimeSpan in Xaml

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-5.0

I am unable to set a property of type TimeSpan from xaml on my dependency object and am looking for if there's a way to get this to work.

```
Xaml: <local:MyDependencyObject Time="00:00:05"/>
```

Time is a dependency property of type TimeSpan.
Please tell me how can I set a dependency property of type (TimeSpan) in xaml.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/992372/using-silverlight-dispatchertimer-is-there-a-better-way-dependencyproperty-on

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/eb5e8549-6759-4c96-86cb-aab001fd8a00/how-to-set-a-timespan-in-xaml

Answer (score 1):

`TotalMinutes` is a `Double`, but the [D format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx#DFormatString) is only supported for integral types such as `Int32`. A format string such as `{}{0:D1} h {1:D1} min ({2} min)` should work.

**OR**

**Try This way :**

```
 <TextBlock>
        <TextBlock.Text>
            <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0:D2}:{1:D2}">
                <Binding Path="MyTime.Hours" />
                <Binding Path="MyTime.Minutes" />
            </MultiBinding>
        </TextBlock.Text>
    </TextBlock>
```

Answer (score 0):

I Did it from code Behind.

```
public partial class MainPage : UserControl
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MessageBox.Show(IsSpinning.ToString());

    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsSpinningProperty =
DependencyProperty.Register(
"IsSpinning", typeof(TimeSpan),
typeof(TimeSpan), null
);

    public TimeSpan IsSpinning
    {
        get { return (TimeSpan)GetValue(IsSpinningProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IsSpinningProperty, value); }
    }
}
```